# Access 2007 listbox: how to click programatically?

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, click

I cannot find any solution to my problem:
I have a listbox and macro working as a search engine. When I search new entries I would like to "click" the first newly found entry. But all I can do is select the item.

In other words I do not want to execute click event by myself - it should be done automatically - like normal mouse click.

It is important to "click it" because I have set onclick event.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "click" a control, you call its OnClick event from your code:

```
Call YourListBox_Click
```

Or you move the code from the OnClick subfunction to a separate (sub)function, then call this from both the OnClick subfunction as well as from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Do you mean it is not possible to programatically "click" listbox entry?

Comment: No, you call the event, that's it.

Comment: Sad face... oh well at least now I know that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single select list, you can simply set the `ListIndex` property of your listbox:

```
listboxControl.ListIndex = 0 ' for the first item
listboxControl.ListIndex = 1 ' for the second item, etc.
```

This will automatically execute the event handler.